# Lock efficiency problem in high contention environment？

Tags: c, locking

"For high levels of contention, lock algorithms that rely on local spinning (e.g., MCS) or on a hierarchical approach (e.g., AHMCS) are well suited (see Section 2.1.2). Light lock algorithms (e.g., Spinlock) and lock algorithms using a parking waiting policy must be avoided when possible."   --from litl papre;

Why are locking algorithms with long locking paths (such as MCS locks) more efficient than lightweight locks (such as spin locks) in high contention?

I know from some papers that spin locks are less efficient under high contention because of the huge traffic overhead caused by cache row failure, so why are locking algorithms with longer locking paths (MCS, two-level locking, etc.) more efficient? Is it just because MCS locks on to the local variable address to spin?and why no parking policy in high contention?

Answer (score 1):

It is not about being "more efficient", it is about being less bad. If you have 100s of threads spinning on the same lock, they will waste lots of CPU time that could be better used by the thread already holding the lock.

Like you say, a spinlock is good if you almost always get the lock on the first attempt - low contention.

When there are lots and lots of threads, it can be much more efficient for them to go to sleep, as they will likely have to wait for a long time anyway. By sleeping, they leave CPU resources to those threads that *can* do some productive work.

Comment: thanks,  but why those lock althorithms with longer locking path are better than Lightweight lock algorithm （eg .spinlock) in high contention?

Comment: In a "high contention" situation, the spinlock is almost always already locked, so threads will have to spin for a very long time before they can successfully get a lock. That really sucks, performance-wise. In that situation, *anything else* will be better.